# CS1069: The type name 'RegistryKey' could not be found in the namespace

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I use VS 2019 .NET Core app and getting this type of error

CS1069: The type name 'RegistryKey' could not be found in the namespace "Microsoft.Win32". This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry, version=4.1.3.0, Culture="neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f711d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

What causing it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the NuGet Package `Microsoft.Win32.Registry`?

The "Registry" has not be part of .NET Core. For more info, you can refer to [`Use the Windows Compatibility Pack to port code to .NET Core`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the message itself puts it, it´s just a matter of adding a reference to that assembly. Add this to your .csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.4.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```